# Audit database plugin with PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, jenkins, driver

I'm trying to use the audit database plugin with postgresql without success.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+To+Database+Plugin

My DB is up and running, an other plugin called Database charts works well with postgresql, I configured the Driver as **org.postgresql.Driver** but always got a error

> **org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: org.postgresql.Driver**

Does anyone succeed to use PG with this plugin ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to put the PostgreSQL JDBC driver on the Jenkins classpath.

Comment: Yes but so why are the others plugins works well actually with PostgreSQL as I indicated ?

Comment: You need to download PostgresJDBC driver and place it on jenkins/WEB-INF/lib directory to load this driver.

And then configure Jenkins following installation steps on wiki.

I've used it with mysql driver and works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Older thread, but ran into this issue today, and needed to figure out which plugin directory I needed to add the driver to.
Followed the above posters good advice, and here is how I configured PostgreSQL to work with the Audit to Database Plugin.

I already had the Global Database Plugin installed and configured for PostgreSQL, so I just needed to copy the postgres driver from that plugin dir to the "audit2db" plugin dir:

cp -p /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/database-postgresql/WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/audit2db/WEB-INF/lib

As far as configuring the JDBC driver and URL refered to the official PostgreSQL docs:  https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

JDBC Driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
JDBC Url: jdbc:postgresql:jenkins

Hope this helps

Comment: I also had Global Database Plugin installed and configured for PostgreSQL so i copied the jar to audit2db plugin dir :JDBC Driver class
org.postgresql.Driver
JDBC Url
jdbc:postgresql://172.16.4.26:5432/Jenkins_Audit
User:postgres Pwd:postgres.                                                                                                      When i click on test connection i get :"org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available".I am sure my postgres details are correct.How can i solve this ?